# With statement and python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, with-statement

I am a noob in python trying to understand the threading module.
I am using python 2.7.One of the motivation for with_statement in python was given to be code pattern of

```
with threading.Lock():
        //User defined function in a new thread
```

I am not sure if I have understood it correctly but my initial assumption is this code should aquire a lock on mainthread  which is released once the child threads are complete.
Yet this script

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading
import time
import functools
#import contextlib
#Thread module for dealing with lower level thread operations.Thread is limited use Threading instead.

def timeit(fn):
    '''Timeit function like this doesnot work with the thread calls'''
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        fn(*args,**kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        threadID = ""
        print ("Duration for func %s :%d\n"%(fn.__name__ +"_"+ threading.current_thread().name ,end-start))
    return wrapper

exitFlag = 0

@timeit
def print_time(counter,delay):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            thread.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print("%s : %s_%d"%(threading.current_thread().name,time.ctime(time.time()),counter))
        counter -= 1

class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID,name,counter,delay):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.delay = delay

    def run(self):
        print("Starting%s\n" % self.name)
        print_time(self.counter, self.delay)
        print("Exiting%s\n" % self.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    print_time(5, 1)
     threadLock = threading.Lock()
     threads = []
     thread1 = Mythread(1,"Thread1",5,1)
     thread2 = Mythread(2,"Thread2",5,2)
     thread1.start()
     thread2.start()
     threads.append(thread1)
     threads.append(thread2)
     for t in threads:
         t.join()
    '''
    thread1 = Mythread(1,"Thread1",5,1)
    thread2 = Mythread(2,"Thread2",5,2)
    lock = threading.Lock()
    with lock:
        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()

    print("Exiting main thread ")
```

Produces following output:

```
StartingThread1

StartingThread2

Exiting main thread 
Thread1 : Sat May 04 02:21:54 2013_5
Thread1 : Sat May 04 02:21:55 2013_4
Thread2 : Sat May 04 02:21:55 2013_5
Thread1 : Sat May 04 02:21:56 2013_3
Thread1 : Sat May 04 02:21:57 2013_2
Thread2 : Sat May 04 02:21:57 2013_4
Thread1 : Sat May 04 02:21:58 2013_1
Duration for func print_time_Thread1 :5

ExitingThread1

Thread2 : Sat May 04 02:21:59 2013_3
Thread2 : Sat May 04 02:22:01 2013_2
Thread2 : Sat May 04 02:22:03 2013_1
Duration for func print_time_Thread2 :10

ExitingThread2
```

Please help me understand why the locking doesnot work with the with_statement like this or have I completely misunderstood the concept.I am confused why I get directly to print("Exiting main thread") even by defining a lock

Comment: There's generally no point in creating a lock that you don't share with any other threads. What are you hoping the lock will protect you from here?

Comment: What I am trying to do here is proceed to this statement
 print("Exiting main thread ")
after this:
 with lock:
  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
Now this works when I explicity call
  thread1.join()
  thread2.join()
but I will prefer using with_statement as it looks more clean.

Comment: As a side note: You're not calling `join` on the threads, nor are you setting them to `daemon=True`. This is illegal. It will work in some situations (but different ones on different platforms!), but you should never rely on it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I will prefer using with_statement as it looks more clean". It's doing something completely different, so it will have a completely different effect. A `Lock` isn't even the same kind of object as a `Thread`. It's like saying "I'm writing `map(print, [1,2,3])` instead of `2+4` because I looks cleaner".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your existing `lock` basically does nothing. No other thread has a reference to it, so it can't possibly cause anyone to block anywhere. The only thing it can possibly do is waste a few microseconds. So this:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

... is pretty much equivalent to:

```
time.sleep(0.001)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

And I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

If you want to force the threads to run sequentially, the *easiest* way to do that is to just not use threads.

Or, if you must use threads, just wait for one to finish before starting the next:

```
thread1 = Mythread(1,"Thread1",5,1)
thread2 = Mythread(2,"Thread2",5,2)
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.start()
thread2.join()
```

If you want to make the threads serialize themselves, without any help from outside, you have to give them a lock that they can share. For example:

```
class Mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID,name,counter,delay,lock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = lock
        # ...
    def run(self):
        with self.lock:
            # ...
```

Now, to call them:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
thread1 = Mythread(1,"Thread1",5,1, lock)
thread2 = Mythread(2,"Thread2",5,2, lock)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
# ...
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Now, when each thread starts up, it will try to grab the lock. One will succeed, the other will block until the first one finishes with the lock (by exiting its `with` statement).

---

If you don't want to serialize the threads, you just want the main thread to wait on all the other threads' completion… all you need for that is `join`. That's exactly what `join` is for. There's no need to add anything else.

---

If you really want to, you can daemonize the threads and wait on a sync object instead. I can't think of an easy way to do this with a lock, but it should be pretty easy with a `BoundedSemaphore`, or a `Condition` (although you'll have to wait on the condition twice). But this is a very silly thing to do, so I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: where I can do
pre:
 with lock:
  // f(io_peration1)
  // f(io_operation2)
 f(processing on generated output files)

Comment: My code encounters this pattern repeatedly where I do this in every task:

 Task 1:
  with lock:
   // f(io_peration1)
   // f(io_operation2)
   f(processing on generated output files_level1)
 Task 2:
  with lock:
   // f(io_peration level1 files)
   // f(io_operation level1 files)
   f(processing on generated output files_level2)

Comment: We are trying to achieve a plugin architecture where I can put some Task1.py Task2.py
in a plugin directory

So I would like to abstract this as a seperate function which can call all the task in a loop.
 
I am kinda of newbie with python so I am not familiar yet with entire api.I will explore a bit more about 
setDaemon.But thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Rahuketu86: If the locking has to be done inside each thread, but it also has to be transparent to the people writing `Task1.py`, etc., you probably want to write a simple wrapper function (or class) that accepts a plugin module/class/function and calls its code with the lock. (If you don't need it to be _transparent_, just _simple_, maybe just write a decorator instead, so each plugin just has to add one `@lockable_plugin` line.)

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403593/with-statement-and-threading-making-function-execute-before-run

Comment: [with-statement-and-threadingfunction-execute-before-run] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403593/with-statement-and-threading-making-function-execute-before-run)I have posted a solution with thread abstracted out using context manager.Now I will try to incorporate your suggestion about locking to implement a some sort functionality where I can have Task2 /Task4  dependent on Task1.Of course machinery has to be abstract out in a way that user can just specify dependency in a config file and rest is handled within the code via decorator. By the way do you have any comments on new question?